# Html5 drag and drop onto raphael canvas doesnt work in firefox

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, raphael

So I tried using HTML 5's Drag and Drop features with Raphael. Chrome triggers the ondragstart event but firefox doesn't. Even though, according to all reports, ondragstart is supported by Firefox.

here's the html

```
<li><a href="#" id = "symbol1"><img src ="img/symbol1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="symbolone(event)"></img></a>
```

here's the jquery/js

```
function symbolone(event){
    console.log("symbolonecalleddog");
    insertSymbols(1); 
};
function insertSymbols(symboltype){
//symbol 1
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
/* canvas is the html div that stores my raphael paper*/
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){
    console.log("mouseup");
    var eleoffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    x = e.pageX - eleoffset.left;
    y = e.pageY - eleoffset.top;
    console.log("x : "+x+" y : "+y);
    var foo = drawSymbol(x,y, symboltype);
    $("#canvas").unbind('mouseup');
    symbolcreated(foo);
    setxy(x,y);
});
};
```

I am able to see all the console.log results in the chrome console. but not in the Firefox/Firebug console.

Comment: Once try by replacing this in your html code. `<img src ="img/symbol1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="symbolone(event)" />`

Comment: That didn't help. Also, another bug I have is that in this method, I can't click on elements inside the div that overlay my raphael paper.